# flex channel.security.error

Tags: apache-flex, security, crossdomain.xml

I am encountering a weird problem. I have a flex application that calls a HTTPService from another domain to retrieve some data. I have created a crossdomain.xml in my flex application with `<allow-access-from domain="*"/>`.

When i run my application http://localhost:7001/project/test.html, i can retrieve the data without error.

But if i run my application http://172.17.10.17:7001/project/test.html, i encounter the Channel.Security.Error. Please help me out on this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try to type `http://172.17.10.17:7001/crossdomain.xml` in your browser. What is the result?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the quotes.

```
access-from domain=*/>
```